# Can you find the killer

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, mystery

Source [BRiddles.com](http://briddles.com?source=stack)

Find the killer: [image]

The killer is someone inside the store. I have no idea of the answer though.

Comment: How do you even know if killer's still inside the store?

Comment: Its inside... i Have no idea of answer though

Comment: As of now, all 3 of them have been declared killers. So, what now?

Comment: Was there any info other than "find the killer" that came with the image?

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if the image was https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwFgo.jpg.

Comment: I feel like this is too broad, OP does not know the answer, and all 3 people have been accused.

Comment: briddles.com provides answers for all their 'puzzles'.  If this puzzle was copied from there, the asker should absolutely know the answer, or should be able to easily acquire the answer.

Comment: It's also interesting that whois tells us the `briddles.com` domain name was only registered seven months ago..  but they have posts whose URLs date them from as far back as 2010.  While their "Recent puzzles" column does show the current date, their links actually go to puzzles which appear (again based upon URL) to have been posted in 2013.  I'll also note that they have an empty "About" section at the bottom of their homepage.  I'm.. actually finding the puzzle of figuring out what's going on with that domain to be more intriguing than the posted puzzle.  :)

Comment: Wayback machine definitely shows the domain as having been parked a year ago, with pictures of horses (seems to have been a misspelling of "bridles"?).  I wonder if somebody bought the domain name and a supply of dodgy puzzles from somewhere, and built a more modern website out of them?  Just weird that it's passing off puzzles from 2013 as "recent", and that the site demonstrably didn't exist in 2013.  And that puzzles from there are getting reposted here with referral tags.

Comment: Actually, I found the source for this [here](http://www.briddles.com/riddle/find-killer), and it looks like the top voted answer is correct.

Comment: @TrevorPowell http://dailybrainteaser.blogspot.com/ was moved to briddles.com.

I mailed them at info@briddles.com and got this reply which seems to be correct.

Comment: If she found the website with the picture, the website also shows the answer. So I think that there was no need to post this here.

Comment: @iiRosie1 yesterday it was puzzle of the day and so answer was hidden

Comment: This puzzle is bogus on a few levels.  The murder apparently made noise (signs of a struggle) which the small register wouldn't cover.  A knife or small gun could be concealed by anyone there, or could have been wiped off and tossed out a window or stashed in clothes.  Killing someone is usually easier to pull off from behind (and there may still be some things getting knocked over just afterward), so the killer may have been right-handed.  The guy paying has keys hanging from his pocket, as though that played a role in entering the doors.  And why leave the door open and stick around?

Comment: @Epanoui bogus is a rude statement to my post

Comment: Sorry if you felt that it's rude.  I'm not insulting you for posting it.  I'm saying that the reason why it's hard to know the answer is that there are many interpretations and it doesn't appear to have a good solution.  A lot of people here were scratching their heads, and the real puzzle is why the puzzle doesn't have a clearer answer which is preferable to the many possibilities people here have presented.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possible theory:

> The killer is the man with the cast

Because:

> The blood stain is on the left side. Both the man who is buying and the cashier are using their right hands. The man with the cast can't use his right hand (assuming his hand is genuinely broken).

Comment: There seems to be more blood on the wall then on the front his shirt. This may suggest that he was attacked from behind by someone whom is right handed.

Comment: @AstroMax being attacked from behind seems implausible given that he is sitting with his back to the wall. If he was able to move, he would have shouted for help. Also, there would be clear marks on the floor. I think the blood on the wall is probably because the shot actually made it from the front to the back.

Comment: I was thinking he may have fell awkwardly to the ground after being attacked but you do have a valid point.

Comment: I did not see your answer and mistakenly posted a duplicate. I also think this is the answer.

Comment: Browsed around online since the OP claims not to know the solution  and this seems to be the answer. OP should mark this as the correct solution as it matches the reasoning given online. Not 100% the site I found is the origin of the image but this solution always came with it, whichever site I found it on.

Comment: @astromax Yup, found it on the site given as source with this same solution.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, the answer is:

> **The woman at the cash register**

Because:

> The chamber is rather big to just be a fitting room, and the only people who have access to storage chambers are employees.

Of course, I might be wrong, it's my first post here so be patient with me :).

Comment: I remember you from programming SE. Welcome.

Comment: Thank you!  More specifically, Programming *Puzzles* :P

Answer (score 5):

A *perfectly reasonable* guess would be that

> The guy offering the cash did it, and the lady is in on it with him. The guy with the cast is an undercover cop, the dead guy was his informant.

Starting the reasoning from the beginning:

> The guy in the back room didn't die quietly. The stuff on the shelves is in disarray, and after a stab wound like that, there's bound to be a lot of noise.
>  The door to the back room is open, and even if it weren't, the noise must have been audible to the whole store. The lady works in the store, so she must certainly have heard it.
>  This definitely rules out any "freak accident" theories.

Therefore, we definitely have a murder going on here.

> However, the lady doesn't look like she is going to be reacting to the noise.

That seems pretty incriminating. However,

> the guy with the money is also behaving suspiciously: when you buy something in a store, you pay first, *while the stuff you are buying is on the counter*. The cash guy, however, has the bag already in hand. It stands to reason that there aren't clothes the guy is buying in that bag. Instead, we would likely find the murder weapon and some bloodstained clothes the cash guy has just changed out of. The cash guy needs a motive. One that would fit everything is that he is running a protection racket, the store is either a front, or "under protection" of the organisation, and the dead guy is a snitch. Since he is obviously a professional, he can use a knife with either hand, so the stab wound's location doesn't contradict his apparent right-handedness.

Now that raises the question, why bother with presenting the money, if all this is true? Well,

> the guy with the cast may very well have entered the store as the murderous couple were in the process of cleaning up. He is probably an undercover cop, since it makes very little sense to browse for jackets when your hand is in a cast and you cannot try the jacket on.

This explains all the bizarre behaviour going on:

> The murderous couple recognised the cop, are pretending that there is nothing special going on, hurriedly trying to act out a regular clothes sale scene. All the while the cop is trying to pretend that he's not there to check out why his informant didn't come out of the store a lot earlier.

I think this reasoning is so foolproof that we could probably just skip the court room altogether.

Doesn't explain where the missing half of the cash guy's right foot went, though. Maybe into the other, slightly Escherisque dimension into which the door seems to open?

Comment: Thorough investigation, but I don't think that's the whole story  ...

Comment: Though I don't believe this is the intended solution, it is an awesome theory.

Comment: @MOehm, yeah, me neither. I may have written the answer under the influence of "Murder on the Orient Express"; just finished reading it a couple of days ago. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the killer is

> The man with the sling.

In the change room

> The shirt that is hanging on the wall has a horizontal stripe similar to the man with the sling. To add to the theory, wearing a sling could be a good way to hide a knife (or similar object) and also deter others from suspecting him.

No hard evidence on this, purely speculation

Comment: Good spot with the striped shirt.

Answer (score 4):

He has already been accused, but:

> the man with the cast

For a reason that, imho, is pretty strong:

> Why would you ever go trying on shirts/coats, while wearing a cast? There's no way you're gonna get that up your sleeve.

Of course,

> He might just be looking... But things like that can be said for any plausible answer.

Comment: He could be after a gift for someone else.  Or know the goods in question and looking for color/style, no need to try it on.

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> **The guy on the counter**

Because:

> He is the only one who could have entered the try room. The other man is still looking for something to try on.

This was the best I could do with such limited information.

Answer (score 2):

Answer

> The man at the cash register

Because

> He seems to have a gun in his pants pocket, and his shirt shows signs of a struggle. The dead boy might have attacked him with his hands before he pulled out the gun and shot him.
>  [image]

Comment: Seems more like car keys than a gun in pocket. Do agree about the shirt though.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, I think the killer is

> The man with the sling

Because

> To add on to what AstroMax said, I think that he might be concealing the item he used to kill the man in the coat he is currently looking at.

Answer (score 2):

> The cashier, because:
>  She's the only one who could have changed out of blood-stained clothing without making a purchase.